# Can you use ehcache 2.1.0 with Hibernate 3.3.x

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, ehcache

ehcache-core-2.1.0.jar seems to have the following dependency, does it imply I cannot use this with hibernnate-core-3.3.x.jars

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I was surprised to learn from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.1.0 that Ehcache 2.1.0 does, in fact, depend on Hibernate.  Why is this the case?  Can one not use Ehcache without Hibernate?  Isn't it Hibernate that should depend on Ehcache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [changelog](http://ehcache.org/changes-report.html), I don't see anything implying you can't use EHCache 2.1.0 with Hibernate 3.3 and that the situation changed between EHCache 2.0.0 and 2.1.0. Couldn't find a clear compatibility matrix though.